# "Открыть с помощью" моей программы. Как сделать?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, windows

В Windows при двойном клике на фото открывается программа для просмотра фотографий.
Как мне сделать это в *своей* программе? Чтобы при двойном клике по фото эта фотография отображалась в `<Image></Image>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это многоходовый процесс.

Для начала, вам нужно настроить ассоциации файлов на клиентской машине, чтобы Windows знала, что при «запуске» картинки она должна открываться в вашем приложении. Прочитать, как именно работает механизм ассоциаций файлов (verbs), лучше всего на MSDN:

- [Verbs and File Associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [How File Associations Work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758090(v=vs.85).aspx)

Теперь, настройка файловых ассоциаций должна происходить от имени администратора и один раз. Это значит, что её место — в *инсталляторе* вашей программы.

Инсталлятор можно создать при помощи Visual Studio. Для Visual Studio 2017, вам нужно для начала установить расширение Installer Projects через VS Marketplace:

[image: инсталляция инсталлятора]

Теперь создаём проект типа «инсталлятор». В нём добавляем ваше приложение для установки в Program Files:

[image: вотсюдамана божольде]

Открываем редактор ассоциаций файлов

[image: на капу нажал?]

и добавляем нашу ассоциацию файлов:

[image: хорошо поработали?]

Отлично. Теперь при «запуске» картинки ОС будет вызывать нашу программу (после инсталляции, разумеется!). Нам надо научить программу понимать имя файла, поданное на вход. Как это сделать, прекрасно расписано [в соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/692851/10105).

Дерзайте!

Comment: Есть ещё путь через ClickOnce, может быть, кто-нибудь распишет отдельным ответом.

Comment: Не согласен. 1. Почему от имени администратора? Разные пользователи могут иметь разные дефаултные программы. 2. Ассоциации должны быть в настройках, а не (только) в инсталляторе.

Comment: @Qwertiy: По факту, программа привносит обычно _новый_ тип документа, поэтому и регистрировать его для отдельного пользователя мало смысла. Да, можно ещё наверняка менять ассоциации для конкретного юзера, но я не знаю встроенного в C#/VS средства, поэтому и не пишу. (Грубые хаки с ручным редактированием реестра я рассматривать не буду.) В любом случае, правильное место по умолчанию для регистрации расширений — именно инсталлятор, и именно для всех пользователей.

Comment: @Qwertiy: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170517-00/?p=96175

Comment: Вот ещё по теме: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx#install

Answer (score 8):

Можно таким образом:

Перегрузить конструктор `public MainWindow()`:

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {       
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public MainWindow(string fileName)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName) && File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                try
                {
                    image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В App.xaml добавить `StartUp`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp2.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"            
             Startup="App_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

В App.xaml.cs добавить метод `App_Startup`:

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = e.Args?.FirstOrDefault();
            MainWindow mainWindow;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
                mainWindow = new MainWindow(fileName);
            else
                mainWindow = new MainWindow();

            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

После этого запускать нужные типы файлов с помощью своей программы.