# Как в WPF(C#) добавить ассоциацию типа файлов моим приложением?

Tags: c#, wpf, файлы

Я делаю IDE и возникла такая проблема: мне надо добавить ассоциацию файлов. То есть, когда пользователь нажимает на файл, открывается моё приложение.
Как передать аргументы, я знаю.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Возможно поможет - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/692828/483580

Comment: Спасибо большое!